# How to store in existing cache collection and update cache in laravel

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-5.5, laravel-cache

```
return Cache::remember('districts.all',60*60, function (){
    return District::all();
});
```

cache collection is

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Dhaka"
 },
 {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Rajshahi"
 },
 {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Barishal"
 }
]
```

now how to add new in districts.all cache

```
 "id":4 ,
 "title":"New District"
```

and also how to update this cache

```
 "id":3,
 "title":"Khulna"
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel doesn't have a special function to update cache directly, but you still can clear `districts.all` and redefine it again with the new value:

```
Cache::forget('districts.all');

$district = new District();
$district->id = 4;
$district->name = "New District";

Cache::remember('districts.all', 60*60, function () use ($district) {
    return District::all()->push($district);
});
```